# フォローした際の通知機能のエラーについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

フォローした際のエラーが解決できなくて困っています。
データがnilとなっていて、どうしてフォローした際にuserのデータが送れていないのかが分かりません。
参考にしたサイトとも同様なコードにしているのですが、分かりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

・userモデル

```
def create_notification_follow!(current_user)
    temp = Notification.where(["visitor_id = ? and visited_id = ? ",current_user.id, id])
    if temp.blank?
      notification = current_user.active_notifications.new(visited_id: id)
      notification.save if notification.valid?
    end
  end
```

・relationshipコントローラー

```
def create
    user = User.find(params[:follow_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    # ここから通知機能
    @user.create_notification_follow!(current_user)
    # ここまで通知機能
    flash[:success] = 'ユーザをフォローしました。'
    redirect_to user
  end
```

・notificationヘルパー

```
when "follow" then
          tag.a(notification.visiter.name, href:users_user_path(@visiter), style:"font-weight: bold;")+"があなたをフォローしました"
```

参考サイト
https://qiita.com/bty__/items/2db1dd4fcd7945b980f7

バージョン
Ruby on Rails 6

Answer (score 0):

```rb
@user.create_notification_follow!(current_user)
```

上記のコードで`@user`が`nil`になっているようですね

ここの処理はフォローされた人に`current_user`からフォローされた通知をしようとしている認識でいいでしょうか?
それでしたら`@user`の部分は`user`が正しいかと思います。

Comment: エラーは消えたんですが、通知が生成されなかったのですがそれはuser.rbの方に問題があるのでしょうか？それともうまく先述のコードからデータが送れていないのでしょうか？

Comment: エラーが出ていないということは処理自体は呼ばれていそうなので、上手く生成されていないとしたら`User`クラスの`create_notification_follow!`の問題でしょうかね

Comment: create_notification_follow!に関するスレを立てたのですが、こちらの質問は解決で終わらせた方がいいでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。最初の質問が解決しているので、次の問題が別スレッドになったのでしたら、こちらは解決でよいかと思います。